# Firebase Database - Admin Panel

Tags: firebase, admin, panel, posts

I am new to **Firebase** and want to provide an easy to use **panel** to my client for adding, editing and removing posts.

In my earlier apps, I used Heroku - **Django** combo that gave me a **pre-built** easy to customize **admin panel** that was very friendly for my client to use

I want something similar for my **Firebase** app that can be used to make modifications to **database**, I know there is database **console** to deal with this stuff but its just **not** user **friendly**, specially for someone with **no technical** background

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: nope, I had to write my own, its a simple web page though.

Comment: Any chance that you share it with us or on github? :)

Comment: Its nothing professional, believe me, so its not worth sharing....I just queried for data and incorporated that with list in html, nothing fancy like Django Panel

Comment: Unfortunately this question doesn't really fall within the guidelines of this forum - it's really for specific coding questions. Please review [How To Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, head over to the Firebase Google Groups Forum as that's going to be a better resource for this type of question.

Comment: Not sure how good it is but, FYI: https://codecanyon.net/item/fireadmin-firebase-dynamic-admin-panel/19063547